# Python selenium headless firefox not working with WSGI in production but working in development mode

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Python selenium headless firefox not working with WSGI (inside django) in production but working in development mode.

> Error:- TimeoutException at / Message: connection refused